# Error when open screen: (child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm trying to open the sign up screen on my app the app crashes and i'm getting this error below. I can't even open the screen so i don't think when is a problem with any dot on the email address. Can someone help me fix this problem?.

Note: i'm begginer on ios development and sorry for my bad english. :-)

Thanks.

**The error:**

```
(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
```

**My code:**

```
struct SignUpView: View {
    
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var confrim_password = ""
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State var dialogErrorMsg: String? = ""
    @State var singedIn = false
    var ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        
        
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            
            if result != nil, error == nil {
                singedIn = true
                
            }else {
                dialogErrorMsg = error?.localizedDescription
                showingAlert = true
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String) {
        

        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            
            if result != nil, error == nil {
                
                let user = ["email": email,
                            "name": username,
                            "id": Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
                            "photoUrl": "none",
                            "premium": "false"]
                
                // Update display name on FirebaseAuth
                let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest?.displayName = username
                changeRequest?.commitChanges()
                
                // Add user to Real-Time DB
                self.ref.child(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "none").setValue(user)
                
                
                
            }else {
                showingAlert = true
                dialogErrorMsg = error?.localizedDescription
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {

            ScrollView {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    Image("logo_transparent").resizable().scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .top)
                        .padding(.top, -40)
                    
                    Text("Sign up")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                        
                    
                    TextField("Usename", text: $username)
                        .frame(height: 45)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding([.horizontal], 4)
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.gray))
                        .padding([.horizontal], 24)
                    
                    
                    TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        .frame(height: 45)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding([.horizontal], 4)
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.gray))
                        .padding([.horizontal], 24)
                        .padding(.top, 13)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                    
                    
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .frame(height: 45)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding([.horizontal], 4)
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.gray))
                        .padding([.horizontal], 24)
                        .padding(.top, 13)
                    
                    
                    SecureField("Confirm Password", text: $confrim_password)
                        .frame(height: 45)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding([.horizontal], 4)
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.gray))
                        .padding([.horizontal], 24)
                        .padding(.top, 13)
                        .padding(.bottom, 25)
                    
                    
                    Text("Sign up")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.system(size: 25))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if username == "" || email == "" || password == "" || confrim_password == "" {
                                showingAlert = true
                                dialogErrorMsg = "Please fill all the values"
                            }else {
                                if password != confrim_password {
                                    showingAlert = true
                                    dialogErrorMsg = "Passwords do not match"
                                }else {
                                    signUp(username: username, email: email, password: password)
                                    signIn(email: email, password: password)
                                }
                            }
                        }.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert, content: {
                            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(dialogErrorMsg!), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))

                        })
                    
                    // Navigate to SelectProfileImageView when the user is singed in
                    NavigationLink("", destination: SelectProfileImageView().navigationTitle("Set Profile Picture").navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline), isActive: $singedIn)

                    
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                        LoginView().navigationBarHidden(true)) {
                        Text("Already have an account? Sing in")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                            .padding(.bottom, 300)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    
                }.navigationBarHidden(true)
                
            }.navigationBarHidden(true)
        

        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationTitle("")
    }
}

struct SignUpView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignUpView()
    }
}
```

Comment: is "SVProgressHUD" the library from github. If so, I think it is not meant to 
be used in SwiftUI, especially trying to popup something from within a onTapGesture 
through your functions signUp and signIn. Re-think your code for SwiftUI without this library.

Comment: @workingdog i tried to run the app without using this library but nothing changed

Comment: your code (wihout the SVProgressHUD) works well for me, even with 3 ".navigationBarHidden(true)"

Comment: show us the code you are using without the library.

Comment: @workingdog i updated the code on the question :-)

Comment: on which line to you get the error?

Comment: @workingdog i'm not getting the error in this file but on my app.swift file (at the @main)

Comment: although I had to comment all the inside of signIn and singUp functions, it works for me.
Can you do the same and see if this still crash for you.

Comment: @workingdog still crashes...

Comment: good news. Could you show how you call your SignUpView. Come to think of it the error could come from anywhere in your code. Obviously not from SignUpView.

Comment: @workingdog Exactly, the error is from another screen witch i have an reference with a empty string, but why the error comes up when i opening the singup screen?, this reference is on the next screen after sign up

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here that the error occurs at:

```
 // Add user to Real-Time DB
 self.ref.child(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "none").setValue(user)
```

you could try replacing that with something similar to this, adjust for your needs:

```
if let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
     self.ref.child("users/\(userid)/").setValue(user)
}
```

Comment: I tried but i still getting this error when i try to open this screen